# Dart RPC API Method using async

Tags: dart, rpc, dart-rpc

Using dart rpc can you label a API method as "async"?  I see in the documentation you can return a future, but when I try to label the method async it seems to create a lot of problems.

Comment: Can you show us some code? If you can return a Future, you can surely make it async.

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to do something, and async is not working as you expect it to work.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for it's just an APIMethod labeled as 'async' like "Future<Result> add(Item i) async".  I had thought the same thing that surely it would work until I realized none of RPC's examples have API methods labeled as async.

Comment: When it's labeled as async I get a "bad parameter error", but I'm passing in the exact type.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you are doing.

Comment: I think the question is more straightforward without code.  Can you use the async label on an API Method in dart rpc?  It's a simple yes or no.  I cannot find an example where the answer is yes.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc/issues/29.  It appears async is not supported.

Comment: What do you mean not supported -- https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc/issues/29#issuecomment-229117660

Comment: It is supported.  i was able to create a test case.  It's odd the rpc documents don't include the use of async.

Answer (score 1):

Async simply allows you to use the await keyword.

See docs [here](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/#async-await).

Answer (score 0):

Async is supported.  Thanks to the support on this thread. https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc/issues/29